# Save Log Analytics API results to Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I start learning the Azure Logic Apps and my first tasks is to store the result of a specific Kusto query from calling the log analytics of azure `https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{guid}/query`.

Currently, I can successfully call the log analytics api using `Http` in Logic App and this is the sample return.

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "UserPrincipalName",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "OperationName",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "ResultDescription",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "AuthMethod",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "TimeGenerated",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "first.name@email.com",
          "Fraud reported - no action taken",
          "Successfully reported fraud",
          "Phone call approval (Authentication phone)",
          "22-01-03 [09:01:03 AM]"
        ],
        [
          "last.name@email.com",
          "Fraud reported - no action taken",
          "Successfully reported fraud",
          "Phone call approval (Authentication phone)",
          "22-02-19 [01:28:29 AM]"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From this result, I'm stuck on how should iterate the `rows` property of the json result and save those data to `Azure Table Storage` which correspond to the `columns` property in the json result.

E.g.,

```
| UserPrincipalName    | OperationName                    | ResultDescription           | AuthMethod                              | TimeGenerated |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| first.name@email.com | Fraud reported - no action taken | Successfully reported fraud | Phone call approval (Authentication phone) | 22-01-03 [09:01:03 AM] |
| last.name@email.com | Fraud reported - no action taken | Successfully reported fraud | Phone call approval (Authentication phone) | 22-02-19 [01:28:29 AM] |
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to achieve this.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Parse_JSON` to extract the inner data of the output provided and then can use `Insert or Replace Entity` action inside a `for_each` loop. Here is the screenshot of my logic app

[image]

In my storage account

[image]

### **UPDATED ANSWER**

Instead of directly using `Insert or Replace Entity` I have Initialised 2 variables and then used `Insert or Merge Entity`. One variable is to iterate inside rows and other is to iterate inside columns using `until` loop and fetched the required values from tables. Here is the screenshot of my logic app.

[image]

[image]

In the first until loop, The iteration continues until rows variable is equal to no of rows. Below is the expression:

```
length(body('Parse_JSON')?['tables']?[0]?['rows'])
```

In the second until loop, The iteration continues until columns variable is equal to no of columns. Below is the expression:

```
length(body('Parse_JSON')?['tables']?[0]?['rows'])
```

Below is the expression I'm using in `Insert or Merge Entity`'s entity

```
{
  "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['tables']?[0]?['columns']?[variables('columns')]?['name']}": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['tables']?[0]?['rows']?[variables('rows')]?[variables('columns')]}"
}
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry if my question confused you but, what I want is to store every record in `rows` corresponding to the `columns` in the json result.

Comment: @klaydze Could you please tell us how do you want the output table to look like?

Comment: Just updated the main question and add some more context. Kindly check again. The data in the json result should save similar to the sample table in the question.

Comment: @klaydze , Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: thank you for this. I'll try and will revert back after I tried it!

Comment: Can you share what is the `inputs` in your `Compose` step in the updated answer?

Comment: @klaydze It is the same HTTP output that you have mentioned in the question. https://i.imgur.com/blztPXt.png

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use a `Parse JSON` action and load your JSON in as sample to generate the schema.

Then use a `For each` (rename them accordingly) to traverse the `rows`, this will then automatically generate an outer `For each` for the `tables`.

This is the trickier part, you need to generate a payload that contains your data with some specific keys that you can then identify in your storage table.

This is my test flow with your data ...

[image: Flow]

... and this is the end result in storage explorer ...

[image: Storage]

The JSON within the entity field in the `Insert Entity` action looks like this ...

```
{
  "Data": "@{items('For_Each_Row')}",
  "PartitionKey": "@{guid()}",
  "RowKey": "@{guid()}"
}
```

I simply used GUID's to make it work but you'd want to come up with some kind of key from your data to make it much more rational.  Maybe the date field or something.